# Windows 10 Docker Machine exit status 255

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

I am running docker on Docker Tool-Box on Windows. I have written some wrong scripts in /var/lib/boot2docker/profile file in the boot2docker vm . Due to which my docker-machine won't start or stop, giving me error exit status 255. I don't want to delete it as it has images and containers running .Can someone suggest how do i recover it.

Below is the error i am getting when i run the following command.

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running                 Unknown   ssh command error:
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :
```

Comment: If you can't ssh into the VM then recovering it will be tricky (and not really a programming problem).  If you delete and recreate the VM you should be able to `docker build` or `docker pull` your images again, and then `docker run` equivalent containers; there shouldn't be important state inside the VM usually.

Comment: Thanks for your response . i deleted the vm and recreated it as suggested by you and had to pull all the images and run again.